# How is Cassandra not consistent but HBase is?

Tags: cassandra, hbase

While going through the reading materials of Cassandra and HBase I found that Cassandra is not consistent but HBase is. Didn't find any proper reading materials for the same.

Could anybody provide any blogs/articles on this topic?

Answer (score 3):

Cassandra is consistent, eventually. Based in Brewer's theorem (also known as CAP theorem), distributed data systems can only guarantee to achieve 2 of the following 3 characteristics:

- Consistency.
- Availability.
- Partition tolerance.

What this means is that Cassandra, in its default configuration, can guarantee to be available and partition tolerant, and there ***may*** be a delay before achieving consistency. But this is configurable, as you can increase the consistency levels for any query, sacrificing partition tolerance.

There are multiple resources in the web, you should look up for "eventual consistency in Cassandra", you can start with [Ed Capriolo's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3_XZDoPnQLA), or this post in [quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-meant-by-eventual-consistency-in-Cassandra)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, since version 1.1 HBase [has two consistency models](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#arch.timelineconsistent.reads):

> **`Consistency.STRONG`** is the default consistency model provided by HBase.
>   In case the table has region replication = 1, or in a table with
>   region replicas but the reads are done with this consistency, **the read
>   is always performed by the primary regions**, so that there will not be
>   any change from the previous behaviour, and the client always observes
>   the latest data.
>
> In case a read is performed with **`Consistency.TIMELINE`**, then the read
>   RPC will be sent to the primary region server first. After a short
>   interval (`hbase.client.primaryCallTimeout.get`, 10ms by default),
>   parallel **RPC for secondary region replicas will also be sent** if the
>   primary does not respond back...

In other words, strong consistency is achieved by allowing reads only against replica that does the writing, while timeline consistent (Ref. Guide makes it a point to differentiate timeline vs eventual consistency) behavior provides highly available reads with low-latency at the expense of a small chance of reading stale data.